# Check if a URL is a YouTube video

Tags: javascript

How can I check if a given URL points to a valid YouTube video?

Comment: check this link , this works :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735459/how-to-validate-youtube-url-in-client-side-in-text-box

Answer (score 0):

Match it with a regular expression.

```
if($parsed[0].match(/youtube\.com/) {
    // affirmative
} else {
    // negative
}
```

I'm calling `match()` on the first element of `$parsed`, but your "domain" portion could very well be the 3rd element if your URL string started with "http://".

There's probably a more rock-solid regex you could use there, but that'll evaluate as true if string contains the `youtube.com` domain.

Answer (score 0):

The below function will return true or false on passing url:

```
function matchYoutubeUrl(url){
var p = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?    (?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
 return (url.match(p)) ? true : false ;
}
```

Comment: i know this is old but it doesn't work for me, it returns false even if the URL is true