# How do I check if a video exists on YouTube, in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, youtube, youtube-api

I am doing [validation for my `Youtube` url text field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28735459/1877909).

I need to check, if the `Youtube` url does not exist I should throw error, I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1383115/1877909) and created the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/vzysD/60/) to check it.

It works for valid url but it does not work for invalid url. All I see is 404 error in `network console`

[image]

Is there a way to check if url exist in client side using `JavaScript` and `jQuery`.

here is my code :

```
var videoID = 'kn8yzJITdvI';//not working 
//var videoID = 'p4kIwWHP8Vc';//working 
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2&alt=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
          $("#result").text(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        // Handle errors here
                        alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);

                    }
});
```

**[JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/vzysD/60/)**

Comment: still stuck on youtube :P

Comment: @hitesh kindly mark as answer to the solution which worked for you, so that other may also get benefit

Comment: @JitendraPancholi : ha ha :P yaaa ;)

Comment: @innomanik : Sorry , I was not online after office hours ... I will accept the correct answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@hitesh, Please remove the datatype:'jsonp' from the ajax request. This way you'll get json string if the video id is available and if its not available then the ajax error callback would be invoked. I tried on your fiddle and its working. Try like this-

```
//var videoID = 'kn8yzJITdvI';//not working 
var videoID = 'p4kIwWHP8Vc';//working 
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2&alt=json",
    //dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
          $("#result").text(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                        // Handle errors here
                        alert('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                    }
});
```

Here is another short implementation for the solution you need-

```
//var videoID = 'kn8yzJITdvI';//not working 
var videoID = 'p4kIwWHP8Vc';//working 

$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'+videoID+'?v=2&alt=jsonc',function(data,status,xhr){
    alert(data.data.title);
}).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: How do I do it in v3? Seems like the call is deprecated now. I'm getting: {"apiVersion":"2.1","error":{"code":410,"message":"No longer available","errors":[{"domain":"GData","code":"NoLongerAvailableException","internalReason":"No longer available"}]}}

Comment: @mila see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383073/how-do-i-check-if-a-video-exists-on-youtube-using-php?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 5):

For those who are looking for a solution using the V3 API, you can do the following:

```
var videoID = 'the_youtube_video_id';
$.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=' + videoID 
           + "&key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&part=COMMA_DELIMITED_VALUE", 
  function (data, status, xhr) {               
    if (data.items.length > 0)
        alert('It is there!')
    else
        alert('Are you sure you about the Id?');

    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr);
}).error(function (xhr, errorType, exception) {
    var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText || xhr.responseText;
    alert(errorMessage);
});
```

For a list of valid `parts` you may visit [the doc page here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list).

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem, see

[jQuery Ajax 404 Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281274/jquery-ajax-404-handling)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-with-datatype-jsonp-will-not-use-error-callback-if-request-fails

Answer (score 1):

From [$.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

**error**

> Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

Answer (score 1):

somebody already had the same problem as you, you cannot check for a 404 error when doing cross-domain requests. You should handle it via a timeout.

[JSONP request error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035557/jsonp-request-error-handling)

Answer (score 1):

Try this on client side:

```
//here, oABCD01234 is YouTube id
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oABCD01234',
    success: function() {
        //it exists!
    },
    error: function(jqXhr) {
        if(jqXhr.status == 400) {
            //it doesn't exist
        }
    }
});
```